# Convert a field to timestamp and insert in CSV

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a number of CSV files, the first field (column) of which is UNIX time in seconds. I need the second field to be the conversion of the first to `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`, but due to carelessness, I forgot to add the code in the CSV generator, and so it's null (blank). So my CSVs looks like this:

```
seconds,timestamp,m_count,f_count
1446076800,,105,37
1446080400,,77,49
1446084000,,69,30
...
1446152400,,88,54
1446156000,,98,37
1446159600,,87,39
```

I also have a dataset that contain apostrophe, like this:

```
1445907600,,twitter,JP,Japan,1
1445907600,,twitter,ZA,South Africa,1
1445907600,,twitter,CL,Chile,1
1445907600,,twitter,CN,People's Republic of China,1
1445907600,,twitter,GR,Greece,1
1445907600,,twitter,MX,Mexico,2
1445907600,,twitter,FR,France,6
```

Now I do not like to generate the CSVs again as it involves long hours (due to API call, rate limiting and stuffs like that). I already have a date conversion formula in Linux shell, like this:

```
$  date -u -d @1446246000 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

but I don't know how to loop through each line, insert the conversion, and update each files. I would like to use sed or awk. (If you could provide solution on both methods or other alternatives, for learning, of myself and the community, that would be great. Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having GNU sed you can use the following command:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+),,/echo "\1",`date -u -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`,/e' t_date.txt
```

`e` - which is GNU specific
`e` makes sed printing the pattern buffer after the command has been executed.

Comment: This works on the above example. However, I have other CSVs that is similar above but the succeeding columns (after the second) uses apostophe and open close parentheses, and the above script breaks on those lines with this message `sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: How you got the error for "-c" ?
Paste the exact sed expression that you are using there ...

Comment: `sed -ri 's/([0-9]+),,/echo "\1",\`date -u -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"\`,/e' *.csv`

Comment: @menorah84 that looks like a shell problem  as we are piping the output of sed to bash, the apostrophe character is not correctly skipped, you can modify the sed expression to skip apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '/^[0-9]/{ $2=strftime("%F %T",$1) }1' filename
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: This also works. Especially on my other CSVs that encounters problem on apostrophes (see my comment on the accepted answer). Since I want it in UTC I need to set the UTC flag, third argument of strftime.
`awk -F, -vOFS="," '/^[0-9]/{ $2=strftime("%F %T",$1, 1) }1' filename`. Greatly appreciate if this is explained. Thanks anyway.